# Format merged and unmerged cells in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have a range in my excel sheet from A1:Q50.

I have highlighted some cells with yellow fill (so that user can identify it as an input cell). Some of these cells are merged.

I am trying to set up a macro, which when triggered, should clear all cells with yellow fill (merged or unmerged) to No fill in the range A1:Q50

This code is not working

```
    '---START REMOVE YELLOW COLOR----

'Step 1 : Loop through all selected sheets

Dim ws              As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    
    'Select all cells in the selected worksheet
    
    Range("A1:Q50").Select
    
    'Finds all cells filled with yellow color and removes it
    
    If cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
        cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
    End If
    
Next ws

'---END REMOVE YELLOW COLOR----
```

Comment: You probably should make these cells a named range so that you can refer to these range directly instead of looping through every cells and check its color property. Are these "input cells" fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above by [Raymond Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15597936/raymond-wu), it will be ideal to have a named range. It provides additional flexibility

```
    '---START REMOVE YELLOW COLOR----

'Step 1 : Loop through all selected sheets

Dim ws  As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    
    'Select all cells in the selected worksheet
    
    Set selectedRange = Range("A1:Q50") 
' if using a range named MyRange then it'll become
' Set selectedRange = Range("MyRange")


    ' Loop over all cells in range                
    For Each cell In selectedRange.Cells
    
        'Finds all cells filled with yellow color and removes it

         If cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
           cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    Next 
Next ws
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting and making it more readable